# There is no NDK , CMake and LLDB in my sdk Manager in Android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-manager

I tried to use c codes in my java code . so I searched and found this guide in developer android site :

[What I want to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgfW1.jpg)

my next step was opening my SDK manager :

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAGBx.jpg)

as you see there is no NDK , CMAKE and LLDB in SDK manager (SDK tools) .
my android studio version is : 2.2.2
and my SDK platform version is: Android 7.0 (Nougat)
and also my internet access is ok , but SDK manager doesn't show all the items I need to download.

please guide me about it , thanks

Comment: IMHO, it's time to upgrade to AS 2.3

Comment: I downloaded that , but i can't see the ndk , cmake and lldb in sdk tools list 

Comment: You probably performed 'upgrade', keeping all your settings. But I suggest that you install the new version 'from scratch'.

Comment: Thanks Alex , l will check it.

Comment: @pooyamahmoodi were you able to solve it?